# Create proxy with signalR

Tags: c#, signalr, console-application

I'm working on a signalR website and a signalR client console app that connects to the signalR server but i am having some problems with connecting.

I noticed in some tutorials and other topics that they are using "CreateProxy" method but i don't have this method, can't find it in the object browser either.

My question is if there is a replacement method for this and if there isn't how am i suppose to tell signalR what hub i would like to connect too?

Code:

```
  Connection = new HubConnection(GetUrl());

        while (Connection.State != ConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            var connectionTask = Connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Connected)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Succesvol verbonden!");

                    // Subscribe to receive messages
                    Connection.Received += Connection_Received;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Het is niet gelukt om te verbinden!");
                }

            });

            // Wait till outcome
            connectionTask.Wait();

            // Check if we are succesfully connected
            if (Connection.State != ConnectionState.Connected)
            {
                Connection = new Connection(GetUrl());
            }
            else
            {
                // Send a message
                Connection.Send("Hallooo!").ContinueWith(sendTask =>
                {
                    if (connectionTask.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Het is niet gelukt om een bericht te versturen!");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that your Connection property is not of type HubConnection but of type Connection or IConnection maybe?

If that's the case, you should first cast the Connection back to type HubConnection to be able to use CreateHubProxy():

```
        Connection = new HubConnection(GetUrl());
        var hubProxy = ((HubConnection) Connection).CreateHubProxy("YourHubName");
```

Comment: Thank you! Completely forgot that i was using Connection instead of HubConnection.

Comment: This is not a solid design,  if your code requires a subclass of Connection you should make sure that's what you have.  Casting a reference to a subclass is dangerous.  Someone can change the actual reference to something else and the code will break first at runtime

Comment: True, Anders, but since this is an example, it does show where the CreateHubProxy method is. This is not safe-for-production indeed.